# I need a row of rectangles, how can I name their variables automatically?

Tags: java, object, loops

Maybe it's a bit vague questions, but I'm just learning java and programming(using Stanford videos) and I need to make a row of rectangles to build pyramid. But as I'm doing this in loop, all rectangles get the same variable name and they just "change" places and I only get one rectangle. So how can I name the rectangles differently in loop and add them, because it'd take so long to make them manually.

My code:

```
private void BuildingRow() {
    int Q = BRICK_QUANTITY;
    double length;              // length from row beginning spot           
    length = RowStartSpot(Q);
    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
    {
        GRect brick = new GRect(length, height - BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        add(brick);
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you put them into a length `Q` array?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of rectangles and populate it using your `for` loop. The name of your rectangle will be its place in the array. For example if your rectangle array is called `myRectangles`, your first rectangle is `myRectangles[0]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add them on some sort of list, so you can access them in the future:

```
List<GRect> listOfBricks = new ArrayList<GRect>();
for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
    GRect brick = new GRect(length, height - BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
    listOfBricks.add(brick);
}
```

And then, to access each brick:

```
listOfBricks.get(index);
```

Comment: Ok, I tried the List thing and I got an "error" (altough the program runs): -ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type        - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <GRect>.   However, the program runs, but I still get only one rectangle.

Comment: did you `import java.util.List` or `java.awt.List`?

Comment: I imported java.util.List, however still the same problem. Actually, I noticed that that one rectangle is not even building up. Because it's "leftover" from public void run () where I tested stuff earlier. It seems like the whole method is just not running properly, because I tried to make a random rectangle on the screen and it wouldn't appear. However, I have the method written in run()

Comment: I cannot help you further with the information you've provided, however I pressume it has nothing to do with the actual list, in which case I think this question was resolved. You should probably ask a new question with more information related to this new issue.